# How to Open External URL in Browser and Internal URL in Webview

Tags: android, url, browser, webview, external

My Concern is Loading External URL's in Browser and  Internal URL's in Android WebView. Tried searching all over in stackoverflow but since new Update of google

""" `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`
This method was deprecated in API level 24.
Use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest)` instead. ""

Tried doing below codes but it never worked

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://google.com")) {
            return true;
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

***GETTING This Error : 
Error:(26, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype***

Also, as i googled and got to know, that the method is also deprecated and is no more in use.

Can someone help me out in Parsing External URL's to Browser successfully.

Thank you in advance.

EDITED ONE IS BELOW

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.URL;

public class rut extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rut);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/r.html");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("http://google.com/")) { //check for internal url
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if(url.contains("internal_url")) { //check for internal url
                        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    }
                }});
```

Comment: and also Error:(26, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: Bro i am pasting edited script above in Question, Please check and reply

Comment: Error:(26, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable url